# Вывод текста после ввода команды / Python

Tags: python, input

Как сделать так, чтобы после запуска test.py отображалось "Введите текст", после выполнялась последовательность на основе вводимых фраз:

1. "получить текст"
2. вывести заранее подготовленный текст, расположенный в скрипте (text)
3. "получить инфо"
4. вывести заранее подготовленный текст, расположенный в скрипте (text_1)

Если введённое значение не подходит под условие - вывести "ошибка".

**Сразу оговорюсь, что это не для учебных целей. Испробовал другие готовые скрипты, но они не подходят для своих задач.**

Comment: Можете как то подробнее и менее сумбурно объяснить какое поведение вы ожидаете от программы.

Comment: Ниже привели пример, теперь есть некоторые детали, которые нужно добавить, совсем небольшие. Спасибо за отклик.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = input()
if a.lower() == 'получить текст':
    print('text')
    b = input()
    if b.lower() == 'получить инфо':
        print('info')
    else:
        print('error')
else:
    print('error')

>>> получить текст
text
получить инфо
info
```

- [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)
- [lower](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lower#str.lower)

Comment: Отличный пример, быстро разобрался что к чему. 
После того, как я ввел команду для запуска скрипта "python test.py", как сделать так, чтобы скрипт выдал сообщение "введите текст"?

Comment: `a = input("get text")`

Comment: Благодарю! Как изменить цвет текста и другие атрибуты? Для сайтов знаю, что подключаешь CSS.

Comment: `from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
init()
word = input(Fore.YELLOW + Back.BLUE + '?: ' + Style.RESET_ALL)`

Comment: Как добавить таймер? Чтобы после ввода 'получить текст' появляется текст - print('text') через 1-3 секунды?

Comment: Добавьте time.sleep(3)